# I can't find any elements on the webpage using pytest, but I can find the same elements using console

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, selenium, pytest

I can find the element (using css or xpath) on the page in the console (F12).

```
$$("span.menu-item[data-vars-category-name='Most Popular']")
```

But I can not find the same elements using Selenium (pytest)

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span[data-vars-category-name='Most Popular']”)
```

element code:

```
<span tabindex="0" role="button" on="tap:category--1.scrollTo(duration=200),
                    AMP.setState({selectedCategoryId: -1, showDropdown: false})" data-vars-category-name="Most Popular" class="menu-item item-1 category-selector " data-amp-bind-class="'menu-item item-1 category-selector ' + (
                      ((!selectedCategoryId &amp;&amp; -1 == -2) ||
                      -1 == selectedCategoryId) ? 'selected' : ''
                    )" i-amphtml-binding="" i-amphtml-key="10">Most Popular</span>
```

What am I doing wrong? I probably should take extra steps to find the items on the page.

!!!I can not find any elements on the page:
https://actions.google.com/u/0/amp?url=https://amplify.doordash.com/doordash/restaurant/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZG9vcmRhc2guY29tL3N0b3JlL3BpenotYS1jaGljYWdvLXBhbG8tYWx0by0zNTMv%3Fv%3D090020190919&projectId=doordash-2e718&state=%7B%22phoneNumber%22:%22%22,%22isPickupOrder%22:%22true%22%7D&ei=_lueXbfaEeT19AOf_amQBg&source=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cssselector works. There is an iframe. You can use below code to switch to the frame

```
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

After moving to the iframe, here's how you can get back to the default content:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

I tried with below Java code and it worked

```
        List<WebElement> frames = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
        System.out.println("Frame Size: "+ frames.size());              
        for(WebElement frame:frames){
            try {
                driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
                break;
            }catch(NoSuchFrameException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[data-vars-category-name='Most Popular']")).click();
```